# Runtime Error: Runtime ErrorSegmentation Fault (SIGSEGV) for the code below

Tags: c++

I have solved the parenthesis check problem in gfg. when I checked this code with custom input it's working fine and the output is matched . when I submit this code, it shows

> Runtime Error: Runtime ErrorSegmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)

```
bool ispar(string x)
{
    int n=x.length();
    stack <char> s;
    int i=0;
    while(i<n)
    {
        if(x[i]=='['|| x[i]=='('|| x[i]=='{' )
           s.push(x[i]);
         
        
        else if (x[i]==']'&& s.top()=='['|| x[i]==')'&& s.top()=='('||x[i]=='}'&& s.top()=='{')
               s.pop();
        else
             return 0;
        
        
       i++;
    }
       
    
       return (s.empty());
```

Comment: Suggestion: Use a range-based for loop: `for(char ch : x) { ...` to get rid of all the `x[i]`s

Comment: Crashes are one of a programmer's bestest of friends. They let you know without a doubt that you have a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing `s.top()` without checking if `s` is empty. You should add check for that.

```
else if (!s.empty() && (x[i]==']'&& s.top()=='['|| x[i]==')'&& s.top()=='('||x[i]=='}'&& s.top()=='{'))
       s.pop();
```